# Remove common characters in lists of lists

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists (containing characters), I would like to remove the common characters between these sublists.

For example

```
mylist = list(
list("tata","titi","toto","tete"),
list("fifi","fafa","toto","fefe"),
list("fifi","toto","rere","rara")
)
```

becomes

```
mylist = list(
list("tata","titi","tete"),
list("fafa","fefe"),
list("rere","rara")
)
```

I first created a list of the common elements and tried to substrate this list from the sublist but it does not work

```
common_elements = list(Reduce(intersect, mylist))
mylist = mylist[!(mylist %in% common_elements)]
```

Could you help me ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Just continue from where you are:

```
 mylist2 <- lapply(mylist,\(x)x[!x%in% unlist(common_elements)])
```

---

```
 dput(mylist2)

 list(
      list("tata", "titi", "tete"), 
      list("fifi", "fafa", "fefe"), 
      list("fifi", "rere", "rara")
 )
```

Which is exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

We can use similar solution as in the previous post, by `unnest`ing twice after `enframe` the nested list to a two column tibble. After grouping by 'value', `filter` the rows where the number of distinct elements in 'name' is 1, then `split` the `list` converted (`as.list`) 'value' column by the 'name'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
mylist2 <- enframe(mylist) %>%
    unnest(value)  %>%  
    unnest(value) %>%
    group_by(value) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(name) == 1) %>% 
    with(., split(as.list(value), name)) %>%
    unname
```

-output

```
> str(mylist2)
List of 3
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : chr "tata"
  ..$ : chr "titi"
  ..$ : chr "tete"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "fafa"
  ..$ : chr "fefe"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "rere"
  ..$ : chr "rara"
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation, it is probably better for the elements of the list be atomic vectors, instead of lists themselves. For example like this:

```r
mylist <- list(
    c("tata","titi","toto","tete"),
    c("fifi","fafa","toto","fefe"),
    c("fifi","toto","rere","rara")
)
```

You can convert your original format to this format by saying something like `mylist_atomic <- lapply(mylist, unlist)`.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to filter each element of the list to just the strings that don't appear in >1 list element.

If you don't care about efficiency, here is one straightforward way to achieve this:

```r
appears_in <- function(mylist, string){
    # check how many elements of `mylist` the arg `string` appears in 
    return(sum(sapply(mylist, function(v) string %in% v)))
}

filter_list <- function(mylist){
    result <- vector(mode='list', length=3)
    for (idx in seq_along(mylist)){
        elem <- mylist[[idx]]
        for (string in elem){
            if (appears_in(mylist, string) == 1){
                result[[idx]] <- c(result[[idx]], string)
            }
        }
    }
    return(result)
}
```

Then you can call `filter_list()` like this:

```r
mylist_original <- list(
    c("tata","titi","toto","tete"),
    c("fifi","fafa","toto","fefe"),
    c("fifi","toto","rere","rara")
)

mylist_filtered <- filter_list(mylist_original)

print(mylist_filtered)
# [[1]]
# [1] "tata" "titi" "tete"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "fafa" "fefe"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "rere" "rara"
```

Many ways to skin a cat, and this is one of them.